# Combine $_GET variables before Submit

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I am not really sure if this is possible but here is the problem I cant figure out.

Have a from that results in the this link.

End result Link.

http://www.website.com/index.php?a=price_range_A_B

I can not use a from but i can use Input fields. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Javascript is your best friend for this case. Also, when you say price_range_A_B, did you mean something like "10-20" or the actual string literal "price_range_A_B"? If it's the string lateral then why don't you just append it to your $paath?

Comment: I get a 404 on that link. This is why your question cannot depend on external links to be meaningful. You need to include enough information to make your question answerable without links.

Comment: combine means ?get will be combined as key value and appended to url .default behavior

Comment: it already does what you intend to. Did you even bother to submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** Since the OP changed the question I have updated my answer below.

I am putting an example of how you could do this.

```
<?php  
    $action_path = "index.php";
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitData() {
            var a = null;
            var _A = document.getElementById("_A").value;
            var _B = document.getElementById("_B").value;

            a = "price_range_" + _A + "_" + _B;

            window.location.href = "<?php echo $action_path; ?>?a=" + a;

            return;
        }
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="_A" maxlength="6" size="5" />
    <input type="text" id="_B" maxlength="6" size="5" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitData();" />

    <?php
    // the code to be put after </form> goes here
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I just changed the question because i realized that i can not use froms.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly.