# PHP link with Input boxes but no from

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine $_GET variables before Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795129/combine-get-variables-before-submit)

I am not really sure if this is possible but here is the problem I cant figure out.

I need a way to have two boxes with a price min and max and a button that send the user to a link like this. where A is min price and B is max price.

End result Link.

```
domain/index.php?a=price_range_A_B
```

I can not use a from but i can use Input fields. Any ideas?

Comment: the link is dead, showing HTTP 404 - File not found

Comment: Please be aware that it is standard practice to use `example.com` when creating demonstration URLs.  Please be sure to use it in the future, as to not confuse people that expect the link to work.

Comment: this one is asking for no from and the link is an example

Comment: sorry i realized that i can not use froms in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this with javascript. In the "Submit" button/link/whatever click action, fetch the values of the fields and construct the url. Then either send the browser there, or do an ajax request, depending on your needs.

eg.

```
<script>
  function doSubmit() {
    var fieldA = document.getElementById('fieldA'),
        fieldB = document.getElementById('fieldB'),
        valA = fieldA.value,
        valB = fieldB.value,
        url = "/index.php?a=price_range_" + valA + "_" + valB;

    window.location = url;
  }
</script>
<input id="fieldA" />
<input id="fieldB" />
<input type="button" onclick="doSubmit();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function onclick of button

```
 function value_change(){
    var a=document.getElementById('box1').value();
    var b=document.getElementById('box2').value();
     document.getElementById('linkdiv').innerHTML()="domain/index.php?a=price_range_"+A+"_"+B;
    }
```

where box1 and box2 are ids of max and min price respectively and linkdiv is id od di that shows the link

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="one" type="text" />
<input id="two" type="text" />
<input id="go" type="button" value="button"/>
```

---

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    window.location = "http://google.com/a=price_range_" + $("#one").val() + '_' + $("#two").val();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kTUu5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Max: <input type="textbox" id="max" name="max" value="" />
    <br />
    Min: <input type="textbox" id="min" name="min" value="" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="btn" value="Submit"  onclick="sendData()"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function sendData(){
   var max = document.getElementById('max').value;
   var min = document.getElementById('min').value;
   if(!max || !min){
     alert('Enter max and min value');
     return false;
   }

   window.location = "http://domain/index.php?a=price_range_"+min+"_"+max;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/FhY5a/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it if you can use any client side scripting Like `javascript` or 'Jquery'. You have to bind a click event fubnction on that Submit button. So once you click on that button it will call a function which take the value of those inputbox and prepared a url and send you to that location.

Example:

```
     <input type="text" name="minPrice" id="min" value="" />
     <input type="text" name="maxPrice" id="max" value="" />
     <button type="button" name="Submit" onClick="doSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Now Your `doSubmit()` function.

```
     function doSubmit(){

        var minPrice=document.getElementById('min').value;
        var maxPrice=document.getElementById('max').value;
        var location='domain/index.php?a=price_range_'+minPrice+'_'+maxprice+'';  
        window.location=location;       

     }
```

Now on the `index` page you can easily explode `$_REQUEST['a']` variable like this way

```
      $var=$_REQUEST['a'];
      $explodedVar=explode('_',$var);
      //print_r($explodedVar);
      $minPrice=$explodedVar[2];
      $maxPrice=$explodedvar[3];
```